# how to delete the user if the email is not a valid email

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have included the following code to delete the user if the email is not sent but for some reason, even though when I supplied an invalid email such as sdfsd@hotmail.com, it is still sending it through, is there a way to prevent this?

```
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
if ($mail->send()) {

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../student_registration.php?id=".htmlspecialchars($userid)."&email=".htmlspecialchars($email)."&username=".htmlspecialchars($uid)."'>";

  //  header("Location: ../student_registration.php?id=".htmlspecialchars($userid)."&email=".htmlspecialchars($email)."&username=".htmlspecialchars($uid)."");


} else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     $sql13 = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";

                                 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql13)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
            } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: I can't find any answers a bout this and have tried the following code but not working

Comment: if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@", $email)), "MS")) {
  echo "valid domain";
} else {
  echo "invalid domain"
}

Comment: I guess i should use some kind of preg match and implode function?

Comment: What do you mean it still sends the email to invalid addresses?

Comment: I substituted the $email variable with "EmailAddress" but still doesn't work... I guess there is no way but to let the user activate his or her account in order to verify their email address

Answer (score 1):

Most email/smtp server use `accept before send` policy.  Your message will be accepted by the server before any (instant) delivery attempts to next server in the delivery chain.

AFAIK On most servers during "submission for sending" you may get errors about invalid recipient's domain (missing `MX`, `A` and `AAAA` records), invalid format of the recipient's email addresses **but** no reports about non exiting email account (on the final server).